# WPF Image control load notification

Tags: wpf, image, data-binding

I am using an `Image` WPF control to display some high res images. I am doing this by setting its `Source` property and it takes some 2-3 seconds from setting the property until the image is displayed. During that time I need notify the user that the image is loading, is there any way to do that? Does the `Image` control have any way to notify when the image loading has completed?

Comment: Are the large images downloaded straight from the net?

Comment: Did you try handling [loaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded.aspx) event? also see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadprogress.aspx

Comment: Images are loaded from the local folder.
I will try handling the loaded event, I didn't know about it..

Comment: `Loaded` event does not do the trick since I am only changing the `Source` property to display a new image and that does not trigger the `Loaded` event.
`SourceUpdated` also does not help because it is triggered when property has changed, before the image is loaded.